# tf.train.Saver instance does not close checkpoint files

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory, tensorflow-estimator

In my effort to obtaining the best checkpoint possible following the fitting stage for my model using the Estimator API, I ended up using a tf.train.SessionRunHook where I reference the tf.train.Saver instance created by the estimator to manually save the best checkpoint found so far in the fitting process, to a separate directory. My intention is to let the estimator instance follow it's course when it comes to doing the checkpoints, but if I find a better set of weights then checkpoint the model to a specific directory.
Here is a code snippet to illustrate what i have in mind:

```
class SessRunHOOK(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
     ...  
     def end(self, session):
         ...
         # after each call to estimator.evaluate() if
         # the metrics for this model are the best so far
         # save the checkpoint to a specific directory like so
         saver = session.graph.get_collection('savers')[0]
         saver.save(session,
                    join(best_ckpt_dir, 'ckpt'),
                    global_step = global_step,
                    latest_filename = None,
                    meta_graph_suffix = 'meta',
                    write_meta_graph = True,
                    write_state = True,
                    strip_default_attrs = False)
```

In the model function for the estimator, the hook instance is passed to both train and evaluation hook arguments for the EstimatorSpec.

The Estimator instance is created and used like so:

```
RUN_CONFIG = tf.estimator.RunConfig(

                    save_summary_steps     = None,
                    log_step_count_steps   = None,
                    keep_checkpoint_max    = 3,
                    save_checkpoints_steps = TRAIN_STEPS,
                    session_config         = None

                )
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(

   model_fn  = model_fn,
   params    = ESTIMATOR_PARAMS,
   model_dir = DUMP_DIR,
   config    = RUN_CONFIG 

)

while True:

   estimator.train(train_input_fn, train_steps = TRAIN_STEPS)
   estimator.evaluate(eval_input_fn)
```

What ends up happening is that even tho the estimator instance keeps at most 3  checkpoints in the model_dir as specified in the run config, alongside them it will pile up temporary metafiles. Here is a screenshot of the model_dir with these temp files [image]

The only way to get rid of them is to reboot the system, refreshing the file explorer GUI will not make any difference, leading me to think that there is something wrong with the way I am doing the checkpoints and I would appreciate if someone could point that out.

Eventually it will end up using all the memory on the system yielding the following stack trace:

2018-10-21 04:07:10.571642: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1275] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:184 : Resource exhausted: /home/m232/catalinh/models/orange_juice/dtt/keurig_new_logo_160x160x1_with_negatives/ckpts/model.ckpt-19494.data-00000-of-00001; Too many open files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1278, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1263, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: /home/m232/catalinh/models/orange_juice/dtt/keurig_new_logo_160x160x1_with_negatives/ckpts/model.ckpt-19494.data-00000-of-00001; Too many open files
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

```
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2/_149 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_154_save/RestoreV2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/bin/tensor_dyve", line 11, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/TensorDyve/tensor_dyve.py", line 352, in main
    estimator.train( input_fn = train_input_pipe, steps = TRAIN_STEPS )
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 376, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1145, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1173, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1448, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    log_step_count_steps=self._config.log_step_count_steps) as mon_sess:
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 421, in MonitoredTrainingSession
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 832, in **init**
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 555, in **init**
    self._sess = _RecoverableSession(self._coordinated_creator)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1018, in **init**
    _WrappedSession.**init**(self, self._create_session())
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1023, in _create_session
    return self._sess_creator.create_session()
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 712, in create_session
    self.tf_sess = self._session_creator.create_session()
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 483, in create_session
    init_fn=self._scaffold.init_fn)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 281, in prepare_session
    config=config)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 211, in _restore_checkpoint
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1725, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 877, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1100, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1272, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1291, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: /home/m232/catalinh/models/orange_juice/dtt/keurig_new_logo_160x160x1_with_negatives/ckpts/model.ckpt-19494.data-00000-of-00001; Too many open files
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

```
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2/_149 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_154_save/RestoreV2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

Caused by op 'save/RestoreV2', defined at:
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/bin/tensor_dyve", line 11, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/TensorDyve/tensor_dyve.py", line 352, in main
    estimator.train( input_fn = train_input_pipe, steps = TRAIN_STEPS )
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 376, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1145, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1173, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1448, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    log_step_count_steps=self._config.log_step_count_steps) as mon_sess:
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 421, in MonitoredTrainingSession
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 832, in **init**
    stop_grace_period_secs=stop_grace_period_secs)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 555, in **init**
    self._sess = _RecoverableSession(self._coordinated_creator)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1018, in **init**
    _WrappedSession.**init**(self, self._create_session())
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1023, in _create_session
    return self._sess_creator.create_session()
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 712, in create_session
    self.tf_sess = self._session_creator.create_session()
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 474, in create_session
    self._scaffold.finalize()
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 214, in finalize
    self._saver.build()
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1293, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1330, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 772, in _build_internal
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 450, in _AddShardedRestoreOps
    name="restore_shard"))
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 397, in _AddRestoreOps
    restore_sequentially)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 829, in bulk_restore
    return io_ops.restore_v2(filename_tensor, names, slices, dtypes)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1463, in restore_v2
    shape_and_slices=shape_and_slices, dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3155, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/m232/.virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1717, in **init**
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): /home/m232/catalinh/models/orange_juice/dtt/keurig_new_logo_160x160x1_with_negatives/ckpts/model.ckpt-19494.data-00000-of-00001; Too many open files
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

```
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2/_149 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_154_save/RestoreV2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.